checkpointer started, CheckPointTimeout is 900 *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
opengauss server restart failure due to temporary power outage：
log show：

2024-07-05 10:18:00.508 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [SEGMENT_PAGE] LOG:  Segment-page constants: DF_MAP_SIZE: 8156, DF_MAP_BIT_CNT: 65248, DF_MAP_GROUP_EXTENTS: 4175872, IPBLOCK_SIZE: 8168, EXTENTS_PER_IPBLOCK: 1021, IPBLOCK_GROUP_SIZE: 4090, BMT_HEADER_LEVEL0_TOTAL_PAGES: 8323072, BktMapEntryNumberPerBlock: 2038, BktMapBlockNumber: 25, BktBitMaxMapCnt: 512
2024-07-05 10:18:00.514 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  gaussdb: fsync file "/var/lib/opengauss/data/gaussdb.state.temp" success
2024-07-05 10:18:00.514 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  create gaussdb state file success: db state(STARTING_STATE), server mode(Normal)
2024-07-05 10:18:00.539 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  max_safe_fds = 982, usable_fds = 1000, already_open = 8
The core dump path is an invalid directory
2024-07-05 10:18:00.542 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  the configure file /usr/local/opengauss/etc/gscgroup_opengauss.cfg doesn't exist or the size of configure file has changed. Please create it by root user!
2024-07-05 10:18:00.542 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  Failed to parse cgroup config file.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.544 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [EXECUTOR] WARNING:  Failed to obtain environment value $GAUSSLOG!
2024-07-05 10:18:00.544 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [EXECUTOR] DETAIL:  N/A
2024-07-05 10:18:00.544 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [EXECUTOR] CAUSE:  Incorrect environment value.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.544 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [EXECUTOR] ACTION:  Please refer to backend log for more details.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.545 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  start create thread!
2024-07-05 10:18:00.545 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  create thread end!
2024-07-05 10:18:00.546 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271331714624 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  [Alarm Module]alarm checker started.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.546 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271314933312 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  reaper backend started.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [REDO] LOG:  [mpfl_ulink_file]: unlink global/max_page_flush_lsn sucessfully! ret:4294967295
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  StartupXLOG: biggest_lsn_in_page is set to FFFFFFFF/FFFFFFFF, enable_update_max_page_flush_lsn:0
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  database system timeline: 19
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2024-07-05 09:58:26 CST
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.549 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [DBL_WRT] LOG:  Double write init is not enable.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  redo record is at 0/EA5A3098; shutdown FALSE
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  GTM-Free Mode: start local next csn from checkpoint 14515, next xid 21192
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  startup csnlog without extend at xid:21191, pageno:20
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  StartupXLOG PrintCkpXctlControlFile: [checkPoint] oldCkpLoc:0/EA5A3118, oldRedo:0/EA5A3098, newCkpLoc:0/EA5A3118, newRedo:0/EA5A3098, preCkpLoc:0/EA5A3118
2024-07-05 10:18:00.574 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  [Pgstat] remove statfiles in pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.stat, global/pgstat.stat
2024-07-05 10:18:00.575 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  redo minRecoveryPoint at 0/0; backupStartPoint at 0/0; backupEndRequired FALSE
2024-07-05 10:18:00.575 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  redo starts at 0/EA5A3098
2024-07-05 10:18:00.575 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  set knl_g_set_redo_finish_status to false when starting redo
2024-07-05 10:18:00.577 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271248995904 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  checkpointer started, CheckPointTimeout is 900
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
2024-07-05 10:18:00.578 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271232214592 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  bgwriter started
2024-07-05 10:18:00.582 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271215433280 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  invalidate buffer bgwriter started
2024-07-05 10:18:01.377 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] WARNING:  could not fork new process for connection due to PMstate PM_RECOVERY

when i enter gs_ctl start
show:
2024-07-05 10:18:00.481 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  InitNuma numaNodeNum: 1 numa_distribute_mode: none inheritThreadPool: 0.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.481 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  reserved memory for backend threads is: 220 MB
2024-07-05 10:18:00.481 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  reserved memory for WAL buffers is: 128 MB
2024-07-05 10:18:00.481 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  Set max backend reserve memory is: 348 MB, max dynamic memory is: 11873 MB
2024-07-05 10:18:00.481 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  shared memory 50 Mbytes, memory context 12221 Mbytes, max process memory 12288 Mbytes
2024-07-05 10:18:00.486 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [CACHE] LOG:  set data cache  size(12582912)
2024-07-05 10:18:00.487 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [CACHE] LOG:  set metadata cache  size(4194304)
2024-07-05 10:18:00.508 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [SEGMENT_PAGE] LOG:  Segment-page constants: DF_MAP_SIZE: 8156, DF_MAP_BIT_CNT: 65248, DF_MAP_GROUP_EXTENTS: 4175872, IPBLOCK_SIZE: 8168, EXTENTS_PER_IPBLOCK: 1021, IPBLOCK_GROUP_SIZE: 4090, BMT_HEADER_LEVEL0_TOTAL_PAGES: 8323072, BktMapEntryNumberPerBlock: 2038, BktMapBlockNumber: 25, BktBitMaxMapCnt: 512
2024-07-05 10:18:00.514 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  gaussdb: fsync file "/var/lib/opengauss/data/gaussdb.state.temp" success
2024-07-05 10:18:00.514 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  create gaussdb state file success: db state(STARTING_STATE), server mode(Normal)
2024-07-05 10:18:00.539 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  max_safe_fds = 982, usable_fds = 1000, already_open = 8
The core dump path is an invalid directory
2024-07-05 10:18:00.542 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  the configure file /usr/local/opengauss/etc/gscgroup_opengauss.cfg doesn't exist or the size of configure file has changed. Please create it by root user!
2024-07-05 10:18:00.542 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  Failed to parse cgroup config file.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.544 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [EXECUTOR] WARNING:  Failed to obtain environment value $GAUSSLOG!
2024-07-05 10:18:00.544 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [EXECUTOR] DETAIL:  N/A
2024-07-05 10:18:00.544 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [EXECUTOR] CAUSE:  Incorrect environment value.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.544 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [EXECUTOR] ACTION:  Please refer to backend log for more details.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.545 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  start create thread!
2024-07-05 10:18:00.545 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  create thread end!
2024-07-05 10:18:00.546 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271331714624 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  [Alarm Module]alarm checker started.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.546 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271314933312 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  reaper backend started.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [REDO] LOG:  [mpfl_ulink_file]: unlink global/max_page_flush_lsn sucessfully! ret:4294967295
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  StartupXLOG: biggest_lsn_in_page is set to FFFFFFFF/FFFFFFFF, enable_update_max_page_flush_lsn:0
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  database system timeline: 19
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2024-07-05 09:58:26 CST
2024-07-05 10:18:00.548 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.549 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [DBL_WRT] LOG:  Double write init is not enable.
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  redo record is at 0/EA5A3098; shutdown FALSE
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  GTM-Free Mode: start local next csn from checkpoint 14515, next xid 21192
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  startup csnlog without extend at xid:21191, pageno:20
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2024-07-05 10:18:00.571 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  StartupXLOG PrintCkpXctlControlFile: [checkPoint] oldCkpLoc:0/EA5A3118, oldRedo:0/EA5A3098, newCkpLoc:0/EA5A3118, newRedo:0/EA5A3098, preCkpLoc:0/EA5A3118
2024-07-05 10:18:00.574 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  [Pgstat] remove statfiles in pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.stat, global/pgstat.stat
2024-07-05 10:18:00.575 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  redo minRecoveryPoint at 0/0; backupStartPoint at 0/0; backupEndRequired FALSE
2024-07-05 10:18:00.575 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  redo starts at 0/EA5A3098
2024-07-05 10:18:00.575 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271293560384 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  set knl_g_set_redo_finish_status to false when starting redo
2024-07-05 10:18:00.577 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271248995904 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  checkpointer started, CheckPointTimeout is 900
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
2024-07-05 10:18:00.578 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271232214592 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  bgwriter started
2024-07-05 10:18:00.582 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271215433280 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] LOG:  invalidate buffer bgwriter started
2024-07-05 10:18:01.377 [unknown] [unknown] localhost 140271496149056 0[0:0#0]  0 [BACKEND] WARNING:  could not fork new process for connection due to PMstate PM_RECOVERY
[2024-07-05 10:18:01.378][2878085][][gs_ctl]:  gaussDB state is Coredump

[2024-07-05 10:18:01.378][2878085][][gs_ctl]: stopped waiting
[2024-07-05 10:18:01.378][2878085][][gs_ctl]: could not start server
Examine the log output.

i dont know how to start

Sounds like a bug in OpenGauss, maybe caused by corrupt files after the power loss? This site’s users will probably not be able to help you - you will want to report the bug to the developers and see what they say.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
